# Scoverage and Spray Testkit

Tags: scala, spray-test, scoverage

I'm having trouble running scoverage plugin with the spray testkit. Whenever I run my tests with the scoverage enabled, the tests fails. Without scoverage enabled, it passes.

I tried adding this to my test, at the top of my class to increase the timeout and it still doesn't work.

```
implicit val routeTestTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(20.seconds)
```

I even tried adding this to my application.conf

```
spray.can.server {
    request-timeout = 20s
    remote-address-header = on
}
```

but that fails the tests too.

Has anyone else run into this issue?